# tooltip computed links for asp button after button is clicked

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnID" runat="server"  
   ToolTip='The calculated IDs are: ' OnCommand="showIds"
   CommandArgument='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Year")) + "," +   
   Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Month")) %>'>
  <%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Count")) - Convert.ToInt32(Eval("LittleCount"))%>
  </asp:LinkButton>
  </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

As you can notice the tooltip text is static. In code behind, I do calculate and get some integers ( IDs ) every time the above button is clicked (  `protected void showIds(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) { .... }`) contained as a `List<ExpressionListDictionary>`. ( the asp:LinkButton is contained inside an asp:ListView )

What I want to do, is to change the tooltip into a dynamic one, containing all the already obtained IDs as links. ( Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jLkcs/5/ - but in my case I do need firstly to click the button for calculating the IDs, and after this I would need to change the tooltip text from code as it needs to show the respective IDs, as links if it is possible)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add the behind code too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a class (or id or something) to identify the buttons you can make an jQuery document ready function to change the tooltip with ids to a link containing the ids. 
I modifyed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLkcs/545/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".myLinkButton").each(function() {
           createlink(this);
     });
});

function createlink(obj){
   var ids= $(obj).attr('title');
    var linkHtml="<a href='javascript:alert(" + ids + ")'>link</a>"
   $(obj).attr('title',linkHtml);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply adjust the ToolTip in the codebehind during postback?

```
protected void showIds(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    ((LinkButton)sender).ToolTip = "blahblah";
}
```

Comment: How can I make the ToolTip string property of the LinkButton contain some html tags/css properties and so on? Just add them inside the double quotes? I do need to create this ToolTip to look more like a dialog, all my Ids need to be like some links.

Comment: HTML tooltip specification does not allow any HTML in it, only plain text that shows up when you hover element with a mouse

Answer (score 3):

You can set your sender attributes if the CommandEventArgs CommandName is equal with your defined one

```
public void LinkButton_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("showIds"))
        {
        //
        }
    }
```

Here is an working example, this will work, not counting in what user control LinkButton is used:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public string btnNoTooltip = "No IDs are calculated";
    public string btnTooltip = "The calculated IDs are:";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void LinkButton_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("LinkButtonOrder"))
        {
            LinkButton lkTrigger = (LinkButton)sender;
            if (lkTrigger.ToolTip.Equals(btnNoTooltip))
            {
                lkTrigger.ToolTip = btnTooltip + " " + e.CommandArgument;
            }
            else
            {
                lkTrigger.ToolTip += " " + e.CommandArgument;
            }

            Random random = new Random();
            lkTrigger.CommandArgument = random.Next(0, 100).ToString();

            Label1.Text = "Triggered: " + e.CommandName + " with Argument " + e.CommandArgument;
        }
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

     <h3>LinkButton Command Event Example</h3>

      <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
           Text="Order Item Here"
           CommandName="LinkButtonOrder"               
           ToolTip='No IDs are calculated'
           CommandArgument="01" 
           OnCommand="LinkButton_Command" 
           runat="server"/>

      <br />

      <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton2" 
           Text="Or Order Item Here"
           CommandName="LinkButtonOrder"               
           CommandArgument="02"
           ToolTip='No IDs are calculated' 
           OnCommand="LinkButton_Command" 
           Runat="server"/>

      <br />
      <br />

      <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"/>
    <asp:PlaceHolder id="plhInjectId" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery to generate Tool Tip on Page itself.

1. Add a hidden field for your all the already obtained IDs (comma sepearted) to asp:ListView
2. Populate this hidden in ItemCreated event on server
3. add a class to your link button, say 'ShowHyperlinkOnHover'
4. Bind mouseenter event to class ShowHyperlinkOnHover document.ready function of jquery, this will dynamically generate tool tip. and then on Mouse Over tool tip will be displayed.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on("mouseenter", ".ShowHyperlinkOnHover", function(this){
    // 2 is index of hidden field having comma seperated Ids
    var dynaToolTip;
         $(this).parent("td:nth-child(2)").split(',').each(
        function(oneId) dynaToolTip=dynaToolTip+ anyFomationLogic(oneId);
            );
    $(this).attr('title',dynaToolTip);
   });
   });
   ```